# what should I use instead of array_unique in php?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, duplicates, array-unique

I am getting duplicate data in an array and that data is storing in my DB. I am using array_unique to refine the duplicate data but it is not working. Please tell me is there any other way to make data unique and store in DB this way.

```
if (preg_match($keywords, $links[$i]->href)) {
    if (filter_var($links[$i]->href, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {
        array_push($mainNews, $links[$i]->href);
    }
}
    return (array_unique($mainNews));
```

Error I am getting:

> Undefined array key 1 at C:\xampp\htdocs\pacra-crawlers\modules\crawlers\services\MainNewsRepository.php:46

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mainNewsLinks); $i++) {
        $mainNews = new MainNews();
        $mainNews->newspaper_id = $this->newspaperId;
        $mainNews->sector_id = $sectorId;
        $mainNews->url = $mainNewsLinks[$i];
        $mainNews->save();
    }
    return ['status' => true];
}
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\pacra-crawlers\modules\crawlers\services\MainNewsRepository.php:46
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined array key 1", "C:\xampp\htdocs\pacra-crawlers\modules\crawlers\services\MainNewsRepo
> sitory.php")

Comment: In one part of your code `$mainNews` is an array, in another it's an object. I don't see where `$mainNewsLinks` is initialised. It seems likely that you've confused a variable name somewhere.

Comment: $mainnewsLinks is initialized in repo:                                                                         public function store(array $mainNewsLinks, int $sectorId): array

Comment: @UmairBasit did the proposed solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

[`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) is working however although it is removing duplicates it is maintaining the same keys i.e.

If you had the following items in an array with

```
position/key value
0         a
1         a
2         b
```

array_unique would return

```
position/key value
0         a
2         b
```

which is why you are getting the `Undefined array key` when looping through the array based on the incrementing index `$i`.

Based on your sample you could use a foreach loop since you are only interested in the value eg

```php
   foreach($mainNewsLinks as $mainNewsLink) {
        $mainNews = new MainNews();
        $mainNews->newspaper_id = $this->newspaperId;
        $mainNews->sector_id = $sectorId;
        $mainNews->url = $mainNewsLink;
        $mainNews->save();
    }
```

If you would like to continue indexing or iterating through each element based on an index, you could use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) in your return  eg

```php
return array_values(array_unique($mainNews));
```

from your function to reset the array keys to incrementing indexes